# How much time should be taken by query in oracle if cost is 77

Tags: sql, optimization, oracle10g

How much time should be taken by query in oracle if cost is 77??

Comment: That's an impossible question to answer. How long is a piece of string?

Comment: How can we know the time taken by query using plan table??

Comment: @SouravM: You can't. The query cost is a relative measure only, not an absolute one.

Comment: Can you please tell me some query costing techniques?

Comment: You already have the correct answer, posted by @Tony

Comment: It will be either 77 microseconds or 77 years... approximately.

Comment: Cost value is a cruel joke when estimating how long a query will take to complete. I have had queries with low values run for hours and others with enormous values run in less than a second.  SQL tuning is not a science but an art, you will have to do it a lot and often to get decent with it I am afraid to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the Oracle Performance Tuning Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm#sthref937):

> The cost is an estimated value
>   proportional to the expected resource
>   use needed to execute the statement
>   with a particular plan. The optimizer
>   calculates the cost of access paths
>   and join orders based on the estimated
>   computer resources, which includes
>   I/O, CPU, and memory.
>
> Serial plans with higher costs take
>   more time to execute than those with
>   smaller costs. When using a parallel
>   plan, however, resource use is not
>   directly related to elapsed time.

and

> The cost represents units of work or
>   resource used. The query optimizer
>   uses disk I/O, CPU usage, and memory
>   usage as units of work. So, the cost
>   used by the query optimizer represents
>   an estimate of the number of disk I/Os
>   and the amount of CPU and memory used
>   in performing an operation. The
>   operation can be scanning a table,
>   accessing rows from a table by using
>   an index, joining two tables together,
>   or sorting a row set. The cost of a
>   query plan is the number of work units
>   that are expected to be incurred when
>   the query is executed and its result
>   produced.

Comment: There is one more column in Plan Table i.e other_tag in which there is  paralleltoserial,paralleltoparallel etc.What is the significance of this??

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#sthref1463 for an explanation of OTHER_TAG.  Probably not one you need to worry about right now.