# What does operation column in plan table do?

Tags: oracle10g

What does operation column in plan table do??
I am working on Oracle 10g and I would like to know about the significance of values in that particular column!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same [Oracle 10G Performance Tuning Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#sthref1434) I linked to in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803053/how-much-time-should-be-taken-by-query-in-oracle-if-cost-is-77):

> Name of the internal operation
>   performed in this step. In the first
>   row generated for a statement, the
>   column contains one of the following
>   values:
>
> - DELETE STATEMENT
> - INSERT STATEMENT
> - SELECT STATEMENT
> - UPDATE STATEMENT
>
> See [Table 19-3](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i23461) for more information on values for this column.

I found this by looking in the [index](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/index.htm) under "O" for "Operation".

Answer (score 1):

The `operation` column tells you what kind of operation is being performed here. It can take values like `INSERT STATEMENT`, `HASH JOIN`, `TABLE ACCESS`, or `SORT`.